# Two electric outlets not working

Tags: electrical, receptacle

UPDATE : SOLVED !!

The problem was in the pigtail wiring. I checked the outlet right next it it, and it was burnt even this one was working fine.   By replacing this guy, the other two outlets start working properly!!

[image]

=======ORIGINAL POST================================

Two electric outlets in the kitchen stop working.

The circuit breaker is good; it shows 124v electric supply, but not from the wire on the wall.  Can anybody give me tips on this issue ?

[image: Circuit Beaker]

[image: Wall Wiring]

Location: Dallas TX

Year of Build : 1985

Comment: Did you look to see if any other outlets known to be on the same circuit have stopped working as well?

Comment: Where is the GFCI? Another receptacle? The breaker? If it is on the breaker, how exactly are you measuring the power? Show a picture of the 124.7 panel focusing on the relevant breaker without the multimeter in the way.

Comment: Another clarification - Is there a possibility that there is a GFCI type outlet that is on this same circuit that is upstream of the failing outlet?

Comment: Hmmmm...an additional concern:  With 2 hots on the outlet, I don't think you have true pig-tail wiring.  True pig-tail is the hots are connected together along with a short wire using a wire nut.  Then the short wire goes to the outlet.   Neutrals are connected in the same way. The pic you are showing looks like both hots go to the outlet for connection downstream.   Not terrible, but not best practice. Something (probably a high power device) caused this damage. Strongly suggest you do true pigtailing for this repair.

Comment: Post your update as a self-answer and I'll give you a +1 for it

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely unlikely that you have a cable failure in a wall.  The only time I've encountered it was in my own home and was caused by rodent (mice) damage.   What's far more likely is somewhere in the chain of outlets there is a bad connection.  As others have often said here, the "back stab" outlets are often the cause...esp. in high power circuits like for kitchens or bathrooms (portable heater, hair dryer, etc.)

With the power off, you'll need to remove the affected outlets and inspect for damage.  Best practice is to pig tail the connections that go from one outlet to the next one and connect the pigtail to the screws on the outlet, never use back stab outlets.   They are a known source of failure. If your outlets are older, cheap grade, just replace them with spec grade or commercial grade outlets. They aren't that expensive and are much more robust than the 99 cent specials!

EDIT:  Meant to ask that you are sure there are no tripped GFCI outlets upstream from the non-working outlets?

Comment: Thank you, Mr @George Anderson.  Your assumption was correct. I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: So was it a tripped GFCI or a bad back stab?   Please accept my answer as the correct one bc my kid needs a new pair of shoes!  LOL   Also, you might want to take the tour so you'll know how best to participated here.   It's an awesome site for DIYers.  EDIT:  Just saw your updated original post. Thanks for letting us know what you found, it's very helpful to others.   Still asking for the "correct answer" upvote!  LOL